# Proguard for android obfuscation

Tags: android, proguard, obfuscation, android-proguard

Is there an easy way to handle this rather than changing the package name. Eg: I have the following 10 package names and I wish to obfuscate just one of them and keep rest of the other packages.

- com.myOrg.myApp.pkgNameA
- com.myOrg.myApp.pkgNameB
- com.myOrg.myApp.pkgNameC
- com.myOrg.myApp.pkgNameD
- com.myOrg.myApp.pkgNameE
- com.myOrg.myApp.pkgNameF
- com.myOrg.myApp.pkgNameG
- com.myOrg.myApp.pkgNameH
- com.myOrg.myApp.pkgNameI
- com.myOrg.myApp.pkgNameJ

I wish to obfuscate "com.myOrg.myApp.pkgNameA" and leave the other packages as is. I am presently listing down packages B-J in my proguard file to avoid obfuscating it. If I put "`com.myOrg.myApp.**{*;}`" this doesn't obfuscate "com.myOrg.myApp.pkgNameA" too.

**Part of my proguard file:**

```
-keep class com.myOrg.myApp.pkgNameB.** { *; }
-keep class com.myOrg.myApp.pkgNameC.** { *; }
-keep class com.myOrg.myApp.pkgNameD.** { *; }
-keep class com.myOrg.myApp.pkgNameE.** { *; }
-keep class com.myOrg.myApp.pkgNameF.** { *; }
-keep class com.myOrg.myApp.pkgNameG.** { *; }
-keep class com.myOrg.myApp.pkgNameH.** { *; }
-keep class com.myOrg.myApp.pkgNameI.** { *; }
-keep class com.myOrg.myApp.pkgNameJ.** { *; }
```

Is there any easy way to let proguard file know to keep all the packages except one which needs to be obfuscated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you use the negation operator on the class name?

```
-keep class !com.myOrg.myApp.pkgNameA.** { *; }
```